# How to obey user-set conditions?

Tags: c#, callback, conditional-statements, user-input, steambot

I am developing a custom Steam bot from scratch that will react to numerous callbacks emitted by Steam, like OnConnected, OnTradeOfferReceived etc. The callbacks contain parameters like IDs or data.

I wish to give the user freedom to define how should the system react when a specified callback is received.

This can be easily solved by forcing the user to manually program the "reacting" parts, but I really wish to avoid that, because a big part of the possible user base are not programmers at its slightest.
The already existing SteamBot on GitHub does this, leading to questions like "how to build SteamBot.sln".

I thought of a GUI for specifying conditions and executing actions if the conditions are true, but I fail to come up with how to parse them in code without going through each and every option.

By actions, I mean replying to a trade offer, sending a chat message to someone, adding an item to a live trade etc.

Maybe the GUI should generate the actual code (based on user's input) and recompile the bot? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is too abstract. What are possible actions that can be performed in reaction to callback?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: It is still too abstract :) Maybe you can describe one concrete callback you have troubles with. What data is available in that, what concrete actions are possible (in details). Because for example "sending a chat message to someone" requires just one-two textboxes to specifiy what message and to whom. If you would do that - assume that we have no idea how steam trade work.

Comment: It's not a problem with callbacks, it's how to act how the user wanted when one is received (basically IFTTT). If user says "if callback x then do that". I am asking if anyone has any idea how to check from code if the user supplied condition is true.